# Problems using `findAll(): Flow<T>` on a Micronaut CoroutineCrudRepository

Tags: jpa, repository, micronaut

I'm pretty sure this is just some sort of missing dependency, but I can't seem to use the `CoroutineCrudRepository.findAll(): Flow<T>` method on a micronaut JPA repository.

Other methods work fine as expected (e.g. `save()`, etc), however `findAll()` results in an exception being thrown, as below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert reactive type [class reactor.core.publisher.FluxLift] to type [interface kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow]. Ensure that you have the necessary Reactive module on your classpath. For example for Reactor you should have 'micronaut-reactor'.
```

Adding `micronaut-reactor` to classpath does not make a difference. What am I missing?

Comment: From what I can tell it looks like there's no registered `TypeConverter` for the `ConvertiblePair` of `FluxLift` to `Flow` . Only question - which micronaut module provides such a converter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `micronaut-kotlin` as well.